# Python package management for AWS lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm struggling to understand how best to manage python packages to get zipped up for an AWS lambda function.

In my project folder I have a number of `.py` files. As part of my build process I zip these up and use the AWS APIs to create and publish my lambda function supplying the zip file as part of that call.

Therefore, it is my belief that I need to have all the packages my lambda is dependant on within my project folder.

With that in mind, I call `pip` as follows:

`pip install -t . tzlocal`

This seems to fill my project folder with lots of stuff and I'm unsure if all of it needs to get zipped up into my lambda function deployment e.g.

```
.\pytz
.\pytz-2018.4.dist-info
.\tzlocal
...
...
```

First question - does all of this stuff need to be zipped up into my lambda?

If not, how do I get a package that gives me just the bits I need to go into my zip file?

Coming from a .Net / Node background - with the former I NuGet my package in and it goes into a nice `packages` folder containing just the `.dll` file I need which I then reference into my project.

If I *do* need all of these files is there a way to "put" them somewhere more tidy - like in a packages folder?

Finally, is there a way to just download the binary that I actually need? I've read the problem here is that the Lambda function will need a different binary to the one I use on my desktop development environment (Windows) so not sure how to solve that problem either.

Answer (score 1):

Binary libraries used for example by `numpy` should be compiled on AWS Linux to work on lambda. I find this tutorial useful (https://serverlesscode.com/post/deploy-scikitlearn-on-lamba/). There is even newer version of it which uses docker container so you do not need EC2 instance for compilation and you can do everything locally.

As for the packages: the AWS docs says to install everything to the root, but you may install them all in a `./packages` directory and append it to path in the beginning if the lambda handler code

```
import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()
package_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'packages')
sys.path.append(package_path)
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to add a link to where in the AWS docs it says to install everything in the root please?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html  see step3: `Install any libraries using pip. Again, you install these libraries at the root level of the directory.`